# Why this Agda program won't normalize an expression under a `with` clause?

Tags: agda

On the following Agda program:

```
module Hello where

data   False : Set where
record True  : Set where

data Bool : Set  where
  true  : Bool
  false : Bool

isTrue : Bool -> Set
isTrue true  = True
isTrue false = False

satisfies : {A : Set} -> (p : A -> Bool) -> (x : A) -> Set
satisfies p x = isTrue (p x)

data List (a : Set) : Set where
  []   : List a
  _::_ : a -> List a -> List a

filter : {A : Set} -> (A -> Bool) -> List A -> List A
filter p []         = []
filter p (x :: xs) with p x
... | false = filter p xs
... | true  = x :: filter p xs

data All {A : Set}(P : A -> Set) : List A -> Set where
  vacuo : All P [] 
  holds : (x : A) -> (xs : List A) -> P x -> All P xs -> All P (x :: xs)

filter-lem-b : {A : Set} -> (p : A -> Bool) -> (xs : List A) -> All (satisfies p) (filter p xs)
filter-lem-b p []        = vacuo
filter-lem-b p (x :: xs) with p x
filter-lem-b p (x :: xs) | true  = let u = holds {P = satisfies p} x xs in ?
filter-lem-b p (x :: xs) | false = filter-lem-b p xs
```

The context of the hole says:

```
u  : isTrue (p x) →
     All (λ x₁ → isTrue (p x₁)) xs →
     All (λ x₁ → isTrue (p x₁)) (x :: xs)
```

Why isn't `isTrue (p x)` reduced to `True`, since, on the matched branch, it was already determined that `p x` is `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching does not cause any equalities to be remembered. A match updates the values and types of things:

1. In the type of the right hand side.
2. In other arguments on left hand side.

This updating happens at the point of matching, and no information is carried further. In your case, nothing in the goal type or in other arguments depends on `p x`, so nothing is updated when you match on it.

One solution is using `inspect`, which remembers a proof that a scrutinee is equal to the pattern:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

filter-lem-b : {A : Set} -> (p : A -> Bool) -> (xs : List A) -> All (satisfies p) (filter p xs)
filter-lem-b p []        = vacuo
filter-lem-b p (x :: xs) with p x | inspect p x
... | true  | [ eq ] = holds _ _ (subst isTrue (sym eq) _) (filter-lem-b p xs)
... | false | [ eq ] = filter-lem-b p xs
```

Comment: An alternative (which is easier to understand from first principles but maybe harder to deploy in general) is to put `holds {P = satisfies p} x (filter p xs)` (the definition of `u`) in the place of `inspect p x` in this solution. Putting it there makes it part of the context, so its type will be rewritten when the pattern matching happens.

Comment: @JamesWood I like that solution as well.

Comment: Hmm, interesting... but [this](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~ulfn/papers/afp08/tutorial.pdf) tutorial, on page 23, leaves this as an exercise before introducing that kind of concept, so that's an error I guess?